# Short story about a car that has to always travel above a certain speed

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for a story I read in the late 80s or early 90s that featured a guy living in his car in the future. The best thing I remember about it was that the car could never dip below a a certain speed in miles per hour (I think it was around 100). I believe he was also in competition or conflict with other cars somehow. It would have been in one of those sci fi anthologies but it might have been a best of a year's science fiction type thing.

It's possible the car or a computer in it was the protagonist. Sadly I don't remember that detail.

Also the roads were somehow built for these cars or the cars were designed for these freeways and the cars never left them. I believe it would have been set in the United States.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DIrIvKKT_nk

Comment: Lol no not speed. It was long before that movie and it was a book

Comment: He *lived* in his car?  How did he get food and water?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be [*Code Three*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17166918-code-three) by Rick Raphael.

I read it in book form, but it was first published in parts in magazines. At least one part is [available at Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/19111/19111-h/19111-h.htm).

It's about a future where mile-wide super-highways span North America. The book follows the police who patrol the highways, where speeds reach up to 600 mph. They don't live in their cars forever, but the police do spend days or weeks on patrol, living out of their vehicles during that time. I recall the police car/van was named Beulah.

[image]

Joachim Boaz has [a good summary](https://sciencefictionruminations.com/2016/02/02/book-review-code-three-rick-raphael-1963-and-1964-novelization-1967/):

> In the future, the United States, Mexico, and Canada are crisscrossed by a vast high speed highway network run by NorCon (North American Continental Thruway).  Indicating the complexity of the system are the color codes used in the control stations: “blue and yellow as the high and ultra-high-speed lanes; green and white for the intermediate and slow lanes. Between the blye-and-yellow and the white-and-green was a red band. This was the police emergence lane, never used by other than official vehicles and crossed by the traveling public shifting from one speed lane to another only at sweeping crossovers” (9).  Due to the incredible vehicle speeds (up to 300+ mph) the extreme danger to life and limb, the highway authorities run their own courts and send out perambulating patrols with eleven month tours of duty with continuous ten-day segments on the road.  As the police vehicles must be large enough to house their occupants for extended spells and operate at incredible speeds,  they are sophisticated machines with mounted guns, spray foam to obscure the windshields of speeding vehicles, anti-fire measures, medical equipment, etc….
>
> Code Three takes the form of a series of vignettes that follow a central cast of three characters and their patrols across North America.  First, there’s Patrol Sergeant Ben Martin, an older office with a paternal streak.  He is well-meaning, wedded to the service, and unflappable in the face of danger.  Then there’s the young Canadian office, Patrol Trooper Clay Ferguson, still wet between the ears, a wisecrack and goof who brings along  gourmet groceries to ease the intense tour of duty: “Pâté de foie gras, sharp cheese, a smidgen of cooking wine a handful of spices. You know, essentials” (7).  Then there’s Medical-Surgical Office Kelly Lightfoot, not a full patrol officer, but, with an integral role considering the number of crashes and medical emergencies they encounter.  Although Code Three initially avoids romantic entanglements, Kelly does fall for Ben and a streak of melodrama intervenes.  The three are on their second tour of duty together and their light-hearted jesting, friendship, and familiarity with each other shows through. She does not buck all the trends of a 60s woman heroine, but, her role is integral for the operation.
>
> Ben, Clay, and Kelly travel across North America encountering the gamut of highway related emergencies: a roadside birth, speeding, DUI, a manhunt for dangerous criminals…  Most are short realistic vignettes, in part informed by Raphael’s experience as a journalist, that show the crew at work and the mechanisms of this future world.  A longer story unfolds following the attempt by an incredibly influential and wealthy father to get his son, and drunk driver, off the hook.  The crew is pulled into the NorCon court.  Some cracks in the system appear near the end (the cops themselves are always good!) and the finale is bittersweet.  The highways are dangerous places.

Comment: I thought about this too, but the mandatory lower speed limit part doesn't seem to fit IIRC. Still, could be, +1

Comment: Yup that's it Kenny well done with some pretty sketchy info lol! Thank you.